# Appending nested values to a drop down menu

Tags: php, json, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to access nested data and add it to a drop down menu dynamically. Jquery mobile web app is the use scenario. So ajax calls are making curls to php then returning json to the web app that breaks down the data.

Here is an example of an object (note: it has been decoded in php then will be recoded)

```
[rates] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => rate
                [categoryID] => 
                [duration] => PT60M
                [cost] => 5.00
                [recordID] => PT60M|59
                [summary] => $5 for the first 60 minutes, then $5 for each additional 60 minutes
                [summaryColumns] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => $5.00
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => 60 minutes
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => rate
                [categoryID] => 
                [duration] => PT120M
                [cost] => 10.00
                [recordID] => PT120M|59
                [summary] => $10 for the first 2 hours, then $5 for each additional 60 minutes
                [summaryColumns] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => $10.00
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => 2 hours
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => rate
                [categoryID] => 
                [duration] => PT180M
                [cost] => 15.00
                [recordID] => PT180M|59
                [summary] => $15 for the first 3 hours, then $5 for each additional 60 minutes
                [summaryColumns] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => $15.00
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [type] => rateSummaryColumn
                                [text] => 3 hours
                                [align] => right
                                [lines] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )
```

I need to access the text from the Summary Columns and append them to a Drop down list with the [text] of rates[0].summaryColumns[0].text + rates[0]summaryColumns[1].text. I have an each statement that appends each text as an option but I need to group two of them together - so need to rewrite

```
 var _rate = result.rates;
$.each(_rate, function(i, vDetails) {
                        var vRate = (vDetails.summaryColumns);
                        $.each(vRate, function(i2, vHandle){
                        //console.log(vHandle.text);
                        $('#rates').append($('<option/>').attr("value", vHandle.text).text(vHandle.text));

                        });
                    });
```

make suggestion if you can - thanks.

Comment: group what together? Provide json output instead of php dump.

Comment: And make sure the JSON is valid - the PHP dump isn't.

Comment: I need it to read  in the option selection =  $10.00     2 Hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this worked for me.

```
   var _rate = result.rates;
                        $.each(_rate, function(i) {
                        $('#rates').append($('<option/>').attr("value", _rate[i].cost).text(_rate[i].summaryColumns[0].text + _rate[i].summaryColumns[1].text));
                        });
```

This worked - I might run into a problem if the summary columns extend beyond 2 values under the text property. Thanks for the feedback.